# Get a "for" object in loop

Tags: python

What I'm trying to do first is to add all the values in a tuple or function, I do no know if I'm doing with the best option but finally I achieve it, well, the second it's that in my example code I would like to get the last value of a for loop, because it was the unique idea I had to make it plus all the values, at this moment this code show me the result of the plus oh the all values in a for loop but how can I get the result?

I mean the last value.

This is my code:

```
def fun(*args):
    valores = args
    print valores

    if len(valores) >= 3:
        print 'es mayor'
        suma = 0
        for n in valores:
            suma += n 
            print suma
            #at this line it works fine, the problem is when I want to get the las value of the for loop
            print suma[3]


    else:
        print 'es menor'


fun(10,10,10,10)
```

Thank you for the orientation.

Comment: You can get the last value of `valores` with `valores[-1]`. Since `suma` is an integer, you can't try to index into it.

Comment: `suma` is just the running total. You may mean `valores[3]` or `valores[-1]`. Currently this is printing every time in the loop you need to unindent if you only want it printed at the end. And if this is the case you can just unindent and `print n` as n is the last number.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `sum` function to sum all the numbers in an iterable.

```
def fun(*args):
    valores = args
    print valores

    if len(valores) >= 3:
        print 'es mayor'
        suma = sum(valores)
        print suma
        print valores[-1]
    else:
        print 'es menor'

fun(10,10,10,10)
```